# How to get the date of the weekends?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I would like to use the date of the weekends to use it in the NSLocalNotification, but i don't how to get it, i tried to do it mathematically, but sometimes i gets a number greater than the days of the month.

Comment: I'm afraid your description is insufficient to understand what you want.  But see NSCalendar -- it will give you all sorts of info about a date.

Comment: Please provide the code that you refer to that doesn't work, and tell us what you **expect** it to do.  That way we can help you the best.  My best guess is that you want to determine the next Saturday from the current date?

Comment: Try this http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/Current-Date-iPhone-SDK.html which may solves your problem.

Comment: what the mean by date of weekends..???

Comment: Its like date of Christmas..i.e. 25th :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya — there are many different dates for Christmas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas#Date_of_celebration

Comment: @vikingosegundo : Its amazing to know that, I wasn't knowing that.... So let me change my example by 15 is the Independence day for India for the month of August, irrespective of any calender, caste, creed, race etc ...

Comment: @Ziad: Kindly check my answer and please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that iOS supports several Calendars, I am not sure, if all cultures that uses those calendars have a concept of weekends and if they are always meant to have two days.

Something you also needs to deal with: even in countries that uses the Gregorian calendar a week might start with monday or sunday.

But if we assume that a weekend are equivalent to saturday and sunday, this might be helpful for you:

```
NSDate *referenceDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfThisWeek;
NSDate *saturday;

NSUInteger backupStartWeekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:1]; // ensure week begins at sunday

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
                                startDate:&startOfThisWeek
                                 interval:NULL
                                  forDate:referenceDate];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit].length; //the start of the next week

components.day = components.day - 2;
saturday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components
                                                         toDate:startOfThisWeek
                                                        options:0];

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:backupStartWeekday];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem about getting the date can be solved as :

```
NSCalendar *calender=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange daysRange=[calender rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth=daysRange.length;
//NSLog(@"num of days in current month : %ld",numberOfDaysInMonth);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger dayCount=[dateComponents weekday];
//if today itself is saturday what you want to display? today or upcoming one... then do small changes here, for sat & sun.

NSInteger daysForSaturday=7-dayCount;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSUInteger todaysDate = [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]integerValue];

// NSLog(@"Today is : %@",todaysDate);

NSUInteger comingSaturday=todaysDate+daysForSaturday;    
if (comingSaturday>numberOfDaysInMonth) {
    comingSaturday-=numberOfDaysInMonth;
}
NSUInteger comingSunday=comingSaturday+1;

NSLog(@"Coming.. Sat is : %ld, Sun in : %ld",comingSaturday, comingSunday);
```

Comment: It's what i did, but you might get the number of the day greater than the number of days in a month

Comment: :( ... I dint tried that scenario...wait I will post the correct result even if month changes and even year changes...

Comment: @ZiadTamim: Please check this code, I have checked this code for following cases : 1.Considers for auto-shifting to next month. 2.For Leap years.  And if you still find some bug, kindly let me know.. :)